# How to fix P0301,P0302,P0303,P0304,P0306,P1399 error codes for Honda Accord 2000?

Tags: honda, accord

Make: Honda

Model: Accord

Engine: 3.0L

Year: 2000

Error codes: P0301,P0302,P0303,P0304,P0306,P1399

Knowledge level: I know little about cars

Help needed: Please help me find out what is going on and how to fix it.

Comment: These codes simply indicate misfiring cylinders. Could be many things - spark plugs, coils, high tension leads, vacuum leaks, fuel delivery issues, etc. The question is impossible to answer as it stands, you need to be much more detailed or simply seek professional diagnosis.

Comment: when's the past time a tune up was done. also how many miles? you may be overdue for a valve adjustment.

Comment: I would start by changing the plugs and wires.

Answer (score 1):

**P1399 HONDA - Random Cylinder Misfire Detected**

**Source of Information:**  http://www.autocodes.com/p1399_honda.html

**Possible causes** - Valve clearance out of range - Blocked EGR (exhaust gas recirculation) Passages

**Tech notes:** Adjusting the valves will usually fix this

**When is the code detected?** The control module monitors the crankshaft speed and has detected a misfire condition

**Possible symptoms -** Engine Light ON (or Service Engine Soon Warning Light) - Lack/loss of power - Hard start - Engine hesitation

**P1399 Honda Description** When a misfire occurs, engine speed will fluctuate. If the engine speed fluctuates enough to cause the Crankshaft Position (CKP) sensor signal to vary, the Engine Control Module (ECM) can determine that a misfire is occurring. - Valve clearance out of range

The other codes are secondary codes indicating the cylinder that is misfiring. P0306 for example indicates cylinder #6.